# How to call button action for each cell in SecondVC after selecting cell in FirstVC?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two view controllers with two different table views where the FirstVC sends data to the SecondVC with segue. I have the data coming from a json file and everything works fine. I have a button in the SecondVC *(called likeButton)* that I want when is pressed to show a 'like image' and pressed again goes back to normal image 'not like'. I achieved that and works fine. Also sends the data back to the the FirstVC where is displayed that the image is "like'. I used UserDefaults. My problem is that when you press the button to display the 'like image' in the **SecondVC** inside *likeButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton)* function it gets pressed in every cell. I need to be selected for that particular cell.
I am still new to Xcode. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

This is what I have: **First View Controller**

```
import UIKit

class FirstVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "popDetails" {
            guard let vc = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController,
                let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
            else {
                return
            }

            vc.cocktailsName = drinks[index].cocktailName
            // more data send
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return drinks.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.rowHeight = 260

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "favoriteCell") as! TableViewCell

        cell.cocktailLabel.text = drinks[indexPath.row].cocktailName

        selectedValue = defaults.value(forKey: "myKey") as! String

        if selectedValue == "true" {
            cell.heartImage.image = UIImage(named: "heart")
        } else if selectedValue == "false" {
            cell.heartImage.image = UIImage(named: "transparent")
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popDetails", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

**Second View Controller:**

```
var selectedValue = String()

class SecondVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
    var cocktailsName: String!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var mainCocktails: Cocktails!
    var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    var defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var checked = false

    @IBAction func done(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func likeButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if checked {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"likeButton"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            checked = false
        } else {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"likeButtonOver"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            checked = true
        }

        selectedValue = String(checked)
        defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(selectedValue, forKey: "myKey")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "buttonsCell") as! MainPictureViewCell

        cell.nameLabel.text = cocktailsName
        selectedValue = self.defaults.value(forKey: "myKey") as! String

        if selectedValue == "true" {
            cell.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "likeButtonOver"), for: .normal)
        } else if selectedValue == "false" {
            cell.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "likeButton"), for: .normal)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: currently you care about 1 var selected / not but this should be associated with an indexPath for it to affect 1 cell , so before you go to the second vc hold a reference to the last indexPath clicked

Answer (score 0):

You and place button in cell and make outlet in cellController. Then you have to add target to button in cellForRowAt and provide the tag of indexpath.row to button

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell") as! TableCell
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}
```

}

```
//MARK:- Handel  Button
@objc func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton){
    print(sender.tag)

}
```

Comment: The button that I need to be clicked is in the SecondVC not the first.

Comment: you have to set tag for button that will be index path when you tap on button will acces tag and tag = indexpath so image will chnage only for that index
if you can share images i can help more precisely